# Finite Power of Operator Norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that for any bounded operator A on a normed space, we have
$||A^n||$ $\leq$ $||A||^n$.

I am wondering when the equal sign would be achieved.

Comment: For example if the operator is on a Hilbert space, does the operator being Hermitian or normal makes it achieves the equal sign?

Comment: Yes, it is true for normal operators on a Hilbert space.

Comment: @RobertIsrael is there a fast way to check the other direction of the inequality?

Comment: consider $A$ restricted to the subspace $S$ onto which $\|A v\| = \|A\| \|v\|$ for every $v \in S$. write $A_{max}$ the obtained operator, which is zero on $S^{\perp}$,
the necessary and sufficient condition is that $(A_{max})^n$ is not the zero operator, in that case $\|A\|^n = \|A_{max}\|^n = \|(A_{max})^n\| = \|A^n\|$

Comment: (it clearly works if the space is a Hilbert space, if it is only a Banach or normed  space it should work too)

Comment: @user1952009 That subspace might not be a subspace, and also might be $\{0\}$ even when $A$ satisfies the condition: consider e.g. multiplication by $x$ on $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael :  (what do you mean with might not be subspace ?) and yes you are right, hence sometimes in Hilbert spaces, I'll have to consider the subspace onto which $\|Av\| \ge (\|A\| - \epsilon) \|v\|$ and let tend $\epsilon \to 0$, but I was more asking if things become more complicated in Banach spaces.

Comment: or maybe it works only in finite dimensional space ? (my reasoning for justifying it is a subspace is with the SVD, hence I thought it would work at least in Hilbert spaces too)

Comment: and yes in Banach spaces it has no reason to work, since we don't have anymore $\|u+v\|^2 = \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$ when $u \perp v$

Comment: OK, on Hilbert spaces it is a subspace, the null space of $|A^* A|^{1/2} - \|A\|I$.  On Banach spaces no, e.g. on $\mathbb C^2$ with the $\ell^1$ norm and the matrix $\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr -1 & 1\cr}$, $S$ is the union of multiples of $\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr}$ and of $\pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  sufficient condition (if the space is complete) is that $\|A\|$ is the absolute value of a member of the spectrum of $A$.  In particular, this is true for normal operators on a Hilbert space.

EDIT:
In a non-complete normed space, $A$ extends by continuity to a bounded linear operator $\overline{A}$ on the completion of the space, which is a Banach space: $\overline{A}^n$ has the same norm as $A^n$.  Then the above condition can be applied to $\overline{A}$.

For $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^n$  to hold for all $n$, this condition is necessary as well as sufficient.

Comment: This would also hold for compact operators, correct?

Comment: @RickSanchez : No. There are non-zero compact operators with $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$. For example, $Af=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ on $L^2[0,1]$.