# Power of operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Why is it the case that when A is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space that $||A^n||$ $\leq$ $||A||^n$? I found this question which is similar but not quite the same [Finite Power of Operator Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758572/finite-power-of-operator-norm).

EDIT: Attached picture of the operator norm I am using.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint : if $A,B $ are bounded linear operators,  then

$$||ABx|| \le ||A||\cdot ||Bx|| \le ||A||\cdot ||B|| \cdot ||x||$$

for all  $x $. Hence

$$||AB||\le ||A||\cdot ||B||. $$

Comment: Am I correct in thinking the norms you are referring to here are as follows (if $A,B\in B(H_{1},H_{2})$ and $||\cdot||_{B(H_{1},H_{1})}$ is defined in the picture I added above)?

$$||ABx||_{H_{1}} \le ||A||_{B(H_{1},H_{1})}\cdot ||Bx||_{H_{1}} \le ||A||_{B(H_{1},H_{1})}\cdot ||B||_{B(H_{1},H_{1})} \cdot ||x||_{H_{1}}$$

I think this may now somewhat make sense to me, but I don't see why $||A||_{B(H_{1},H_{1})}$ can be used as a bound for $||ABx||_{H_{1}}$

Comment: The answer here was what I needed to understand your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005389/the-operator-norm-of-the-composition-of-linear-bounded-operators-between-banach

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\|AB\| \le \|A\| \|B\|$