# When is the equality $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^n$ achieved for a bounded linear operator $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. Then
$$\|A^n\| \leq \|A\|\cdots\|A\| = \|A\|^n.$$
I am wondering under what conditions can this inequality be made into an equality? Or equivalently, when does the inequality
$$\|A\|^n \leq \|A^n\|$$
hold?

Comment: with matrices it's enough to be normal. In general I don't know... maybe self adjoint?

Comment: @Exodd For normal, and hence also self-adjoint, operators I am able to prove that $\|A\|^2 = \|A^*\|^2 = \|A^* A\|$, but I was unable to generalize this to arbitrary powers of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To add to my last comment, it seems that string of equalities holds for all bounded linear operators, not just normal or self adjoint ones.

Comment: The equalities hold iff $\|A\|$ is equal to the spectral radius of $A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you, do you know where I can find a proof of this statement?

Comment: It's just my guess. I can give a try to answer.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc This seems to be true as another answer gives the same condition (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758592/823800).

Comment: It seems that your question as well as my answer are  duplicates.

Comment: Even in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, it holds if $A$ is normal.  By the spectral theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar I am new to spectral theory, how does this follow from the spectral theorem (which says that every operator is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on a suitable measure space)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equality $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n$ holds for every $n$ if and only if the spectral radius $r(A)$ is equal $\|A\|. $

The proof goes as follows.
Assume $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n$ for every $n.$ Then $$r(A):=\lim_n\|A^n\|^{1/n}=\|A\|$$ Conversely, assume $r(A)=\|A\|.$ Then $$\|A^k\|\ge r(A^k)=r(A)^k=\|A\|^k\ge\|A^k\|$$
For a normal operator $A$ the spectral radius is equal $\|A\|$, and no Gelfand-Naimark theory is needed in the proof. Namely if $B$ is self-adjoint then $$\|B^{2^{n}}\|=\|B^{2^{n-1}}B^{2^{n-1}}\|=\|B^{2^{n-1}}\|^2$$ Applying induction gives $$\|B^{2^n}\|=\|B\|^{2^n}$$ Hence $$\|B\|=\|B^{2^n}\|^{1/2^n}\longrightarrow r(B)$$
If $A$ is normal then $B:=A^*A$ is self-adjoint. Hence $$\|A^n\|^2=\|(A^n)^*A^n\|=\|(A^*A)^n\|\\ =\|B^n\|=\|B\|^n=\|A^*A\|^n=\|A\|^{2n}$$

Comment: @CBBAM This answer exactly claims that $\|A^n\| = \|A\|^n$ for all $n$ if and only if $\|A\|=r(A)$, where $r$ is the spectral radius.

Comment: Sorry I was confusing myself but now I understand. Thank you for your proof. I have accepted it since I prefer a proof that does not use Gelfand theory. How do we know that $r(A^k) = r(A)^k$?

Comment: $$r(A^k)=\lim_n\|A^{kn}\|^{1/n}=(\lim_n\|A^{kn}\|^{1/kn})^k=r(A)^k$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for all your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

I can prove it for normal operators using functional analysis.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the $C^\star$ algebra generated by $A$ and $I$. If $A$ is normal, this algebra is commutative and unital.

By Gelfand theory we have that $\mathcal{A} \cong C(\sigma(\mathcal{A}))$, let $\hat{\cdot} : \mathcal{A}\rightarrow C(\sigma(\mathcal{A}))$ denote the Gelfand transform. In particular, for any $x\in \mathcal{A}$ we have that $\hat{x} : \sigma(\mathcal{A})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function.

By Gelfand-Neimark theorem: $\hat{\cdot}$ is an isometric $\star$-morphism, meaning that $\|x\| = \|\hat{x}\|_\infty$

For a proof check out Theorem 1.20 in "A course in abstract harmonic analysis" by Gerald B. Folland.

We then in particular have that $\|A^n\| = \|\hat{A}^n\|_\infty$, but for continuous functions we have $\|f^n\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty^n$ which gives the proof.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning functional analysis and have not yet gotten to C* algebras or Gelfand theory, but I will come back to this answer once I have.

Comment: @CBBAM You're welcome. I personally think the book I mention is a good one to learn everything from zero